# How can I catch a US phone number with +1 area code regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following requirement.

I need to validate with Rails that a phone number begins with `+1` and is met with exactly 10 digits after this? So far, I have this regex expression.

```
^+1\d{10}
```

This is not working and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to tweak this to match exactly what I need. Does anyone have any ideas the validation has to catch this exactly.

```
+19564321234
```

etc. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is not working"? `/\A\+\d{10}\z/` should do it. Note you need anchors at both ends, else `"+11111111111111111111"` would match. You also need to escape `"+"`. I suggest you remove the Rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Cary, but I placed this on rubular.com but it doesn't seem to catch the pattern. It says no pattern is found. However, I think Im on the right track though. I'll tweak what you've posted.

Comment: It works fine in Rubular if only a single string is tested at a time (which I understand is what you are doing). See the end of my answer.

Comment: It might be worth it to note that `+19564321234` and `0019564321234` would route to the same phone. You might need to check the second case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your regular expression:

- You have not escaped the plus sign, so it reads, "match the beginning of a line, followed by one or more (`+`) zero-width characters, followed by 10 digits"
- You have omitted an end-of-string anchor, so `\d{10}` will match a string of `10` *or more* digits

You need to write:

```
r = /\A\+\d{10}\z/
```

```
"+1234567890".match? r     #=> true
"1234567890".match? r      #=> false
"+1234567890123".match? r  #=> false
```

I've used the beginning-of-string anchor, `\A`, rather than the beginning-of-line anchor `^`. The latter would be in problem only in some extreme cases, such as:

```
"dog\n+1234567890".match? /^\+\d{10}\z/ #=> true
```

[Start your engine!](https://rubular.com/r/BHefkSFSCjT4JE). To see it [tested against several strings](https://rubular.com/r/0sXBgVp2bIcyW0) one must change the anchors to `^` and `$` and add the multiline (`/m`) modifier.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I apprecaite it.